# How to properly set email signature icon on Mail App?

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, signature

I added my logo in Gmail signature like so:

[image]

it renders perfectly crystal clear, before sent, and after arrived on the other end. I send it to myself and opened it on my MacBook, it looks perfect as is. See below:
[image]

Then I copied that ***exact*** signature to **Mail > Preferences**,

[image]

save it, quit **Mail** App, and tried to send it out. It blows up so huge...

[image]

How do I **solve** this issue? does anyone else face this issue ?

---

I've tried to resize that logo to 100 x 50 px, but it makes my image very **pixelated**.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you send the second mail (in Mail.app)?

Comment: See that drop down to the right of your logo in the signature window? Click it, and I think it will offer options as to size (small, med. original)

Answer (score 0):

The only possible solution I can find is to resize the image but you have already tried that.

Unless apple mail allows resizing the images within signature; I guess we'll have to live like this.